# Add google play services to a project with compile SDK version 21?

Tags: android, google-play-services, onesignal

So I am trying to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'` to my **gradle**. The app level **gradle** is as follow:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 11
    versionName "1.1"

dependencies {
    //    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also here is my project level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I add play services dependency, it results in this error:

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name ' android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches 
the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I tried versions prior to 10.0.1 but got the same result. Also I can't use versions below 9.0.0 because I get this error:

```
Error:(50, 0) Version: 8.4.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.
```

I can't change compile SDK version. It must be **21**. Also this problem is part of a bigger problem: Adding OneSignal to my project so I can send push notifications. I have already used **Firebase** but I have to use OneSignal instead because of it's special features.
Note that all the problems are due to having my compile SDK version down to 21. If I change it to **23** or higher, I can easily add OneSignal to my project.

Comment: You should change buildToolsVersion to `buildToolsVersion "21.0.3"`.

Comment: buildToolsVersion "21.0.3" is not listed in my SDK manager. Also when I change it in **gradle** it says `not all packages are available for download` @Yuliwee

Comment: Make sure buildTooldVersion and compileSdkVersion match. I'm pretty confused anyway that you must use SDK version 21. OneSignal is for newer versions too. And you don't need to add com.google.gms.... dependencies. The OneSignal documentation tells you everything you need to do: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

Comment: Sounds like I have to open another thread and post my main problem which is adding **OneSignal** to my project with compile SDK 21. This way it will be less confusing.@Yuliwee

Comment: WHY do you need compileSdkVersion 21? If it is higher, it will still run on older systems if you don't use newer functions.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't change compile SDK version. **It must be 21.**

Don't confuse `minSdkVersion` with `compileSdkVersion`.
Today we have the version 27, and if you want to use the latest libraries of google play services, firebase, OneSignal you have to change this level avoiding the use of compileSdk = 21.

[Check this post:](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

> `compileSdkVersion` is your way to tell Gradle what version of the Android SDK to compile your app with. Using the new Android SDK is a requirement to use any of the new APIs added in that level.
>
> **It should be emphasized that changing your compileSdkVersion does not change runtime behavior**.
>   **Therefore it is strongly recommended that you always compile with the latest SDK**
>
> If `compileSdkVersion` sets the newest APIs available to you, `minSdkVersion` **is the lower bound for your app.** The minSdkVersion is one of the signals the Google Play Store uses to determine which of a user’s devices an app can be installed on.

Then use the latest OneSignal library, the latest GooglePlayServices library and change your compileSdk to 27.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in my question, for some reason I shouldn't change my compile SDK version. It should remain at 21.

Comment: @saraX In my opinion you should not have any issue changing the compilesdk since it doesn't change the runtime behaviour. But if you have to use today the compileSdk=21 (now we have the version 27) you will have a lot of problem using the new libraries (google play services, firebase, OneSignal....)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add dependency for Google Play services that are already specified in your Choose_Library_Dependency dialogue.
This thing always worked for me.
Just go through the options, you will find the match for Google Play services.

Screenshot : https://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/choose-library-dependency.png